# How to delete key from array and update index?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = array('a', 'b','c');
unset($array[0]);
var_dump($array);

Yields:
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  'b'
  'c'
}
```

How do I, remove array[0] to get ['bb','cc'] (no empty keys):

```
array(1) {
  'b'
  'c'
}
```

Comment: array_values() after the unset would work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check this:

```
$array = array('a', 'b','c');
unset($array[0]);
$array = array_values($array); //reindexing
```

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at [`array_splice()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

```
$array = array_splice($array, 0, 1);
```

If you happen to be removing the first element specifically (and not an arbitrary element in the middle of the array), `array_shift()` is more appropriate.

Comment: Why is this a better choice than unset/array_values? Speed?

Comment: @Bashevis: There is a speed advantage, yes. Arguably even more important, though: it's cleaner and clearer. `array_slice()` is designed to do this exact thing. There's no question what's happening when you see that function call. `unset(); array_values();` accomplishes the same thing but does it in two separate steps, which forces the reader to work out the consequences – i.e., to figure out that it's a way of doing an `array_slice()`.